# Can you use a Bayes classifier to determine if something is NOT in a defined class?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-statistics

I know I can use a Bayes classifier to determine if something is one of N classes, but can I also determine if something is NOT in any of the predefined classes?  Or will a Bayes classifier only find the closest class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an extra class whose membership means "belongs to none of the predefined classes".